# In CMD/Batch, Can I store a value returned by WMIC?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wmic

I am currently working on a script where I want to edit a logged in user's registry remotely.

Currently I ask a computer number from the user which I use to remotely shutdown certain programs on the target machine which is fine.

What I want to do it get the SID for the currently logged on user and store it in a variable which I can then use to automate the registry changes.

```
set /p asset="asset number or IP Address: "
pushd \\%asset%\c$

:: Get SID
for /f "delims= " %%a in ('"wmic path win32_useraccount where name='%UserName%' get sid"') do (
   if not "%%a"=="SID" (          
      set myvar=%%a
      goto :loop_end
   )   
)

:loop_end
echo %%myvar%%=%myvar%

:: End tasks that hold cached versions of their profile to prevent any issues
:: /T /F Allows this script to be run via remote CMD
taskkill /S %asset% /IM "Outlook.exe" /T /F
taskkill /S %asset% /IM "Communicator.exe" /T /F
taskkill /S %asset% /IM "Lync.exe" /T /F
taskkill /S %asset% /IM "Skype.exe" /T /F

timeout /t 20

:: 2007/2010
reg query "\\%asset%\HKEY_USERS\%myvar%\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles"

timeout /t 30
if not ErrorLevel 1 (
  echo. "\\%asset%\HKEY_USERS\%myvar%\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook" was found
  :: reg export "%asset%\%username%\HKEY_USERS\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook" "Outlook2007.reg"
  reg delete "\\%asset%\HKEY_USERS\%myvar%\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles" /f & reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook" & reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles" /v DefaultProfile /t REG_SZ /d "Outlook" /F & reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Exchange\Client\Options" /v PickLogonProfile /t REG_DWORD /d "0" /f
) else (
  echo. "\\%asset%\HKEY_USERS\%myvar%\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook" not found
)

timeout /t 200
```

The only issue I seem to have is it displays my own SID and not the currently logged in users.

Comment: "The only issue I seem to have is it displays my own SID and not the currently logged in users." it's under the code

Comment: because you are telling it to `:)`...`%username%` is the variable for the logged in user.

Comment: Also, Are you assuming that if you `pushd` to a UNC path, it is running the `wmic` command on the remote device?

Comment: I guess you would be right - so %username% will pull from my own machine rather than the remote one. So is there a way to have it run the it for the remote machine?

Comment: Hmm we do have psexec on all machines - so are you saying it would be possible to retrieve that logged on users SID or only my own since I am using psexec?

Comment: Take a look at [`wmic`](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html), particularly at the global switch `/USER`...

Comment: Can't test at the moment, but `WMIC /NODE:othernode computersystem GET name, username` should work (given sufficient privileges).

Comment: `WMIC /NODE` will probably do what you want. If you have to go outside of that, using PowerShell `Invoke-Command` would be in the stated direction of Microsoft system administration.